# Example of a non-trivial ideal of ring of all continuous functions defined on all $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I'm trying to *give an example of a non-trivial ideal of ring of all continuous functions defined on all $\mathbb{R}$.*

But it seems that I don't have any good idea of how to construct this example. And I clearly don't understand the idea of rings of functions well (but it's pretty hard to explain which part exactly). I was searching for an example, but didn't find anything useful (maybe I missed something).

I think that when I understand how to solve this problem, it will help me understand this idea of ring of functions better.

Comment: The ideal of continuous functions vanishing at a given point $a\in\mathbf R$, for instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like, for instance, $7\Bbb Z$ is an ideal of $\Bbb Z$, so happen taking a function $f\ne 0$ and non-invertible of $C(\Bbb R)$. For example $I=\{x^2g(x) |g\in C(\Bbb R)\}$ is an ideal. Also the functions vanishing at a point $x_1$ or at a finite set $x_1,x_2,....,x_n$ form an ideal. (*All this is easy to prove*).

Answer (score 0):

$A:=\mathcal{C}^0(\mathbb{R})$ is a commutative ring, hence it admits ideals, that is additive subgroups of $A$ which are stable under multiplication by any elements of $A$. Regarding your question, try to prove that the set of continuous functions which value at $0$ is $0$ is a non-trivial ideal of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

As well as functions vanishing at one point, you could also take the ideal of functions vanishing at all but finitely many of the positive integers. This is a proper ideal, since it doesn't contain the constant function $1$ and it's non-empty, since it contains the truncated sine function (extended by a straight line to the left).